# How can I insert a Buffer value to mysql database?

Tags: mysql, node.js

So I have the following code:

```
let sql = `INSERT INTO users(email, name, surname, stellarAccount, stellarSeed) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`;
    let new_user = [
      mysql.escape(args.email),
      mysql.escape(args.name),
      mysql.escape(args.surname),
      mysql.escape(keypair.publicKey()),
      mysql.escape(utils.encrypt(Buffer.from(keypair.secret(), "utf-8"))),
    ];

    console.log(await utils.encrypt(Buffer.from(keypair.secret(), "utf-8")));
    con.query(sql, new_user, (err, results, fields) => {
      if (err) {
        return console.error(err.message);
      }

      console.log(results);
    });
```

The problem is that instead of the encrypted value in mysql I have only blank space. I tried to console log the following:

```
utils.encrypt(Buffer.from(keypair.secret(), "utf-8"))
```

and it looked something like this:
<Buffer 01 02 02 00 78 45 8c 88 86 55 00 4f 23 8e 1f 80 a8 1d 3d c4 b0 6a 4c de 3e 60 db 43 51 8d 12 26 56 f3 70 1a 7b 01 89 65 c5 ea 7b 91 ff 71 f6 46 a6 e7 ... 162 more bytes>

In mysql the table charset is utf8mb4 and utf8mb4_0900_ai and the column that is blank is BLOB, also I wanted to set Not Null the column at it's giving me an error, I can't set BLOB to be not null ?
How can I insert the encrypted value in mysql db correcly ?
It is not for a password, I need this value afterwards, but I was thinking that encrypting it in the db would be much better than inserting it there as a plain text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert your buffer to `utf-8` string and then you can save it.

```
buf1.toString('utf8');
```

See [working](https://replit.com/join/czfduyxdqs-shubhamdixit863)

Comment: can I leave mysql column to be VARBINARY(200) or should I change it ?

Comment: also, it is [Object Promise] for me, when I am doing console.log

Comment: You need to await the promise first and then convert it